# Did electrons, right after the big bang, all had the same handedness (like all neutrinos are lefthanded)?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, neutrinos

It is known that all neutrinos are lefthanded (for simplicity I don't discriminate between the technicalities of handedness and helicity), though in the answers of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267035/where-are-all-the-slow-neutrinos) one can read that the major part of the neutrinos is non-relativistic, for various reasons, and that they are extremely hard to observe.

Can it be that also all electrons, at the moment they came into existence after the big bang, had the same handedness?

Because neutrinos haven't interacted with other matter since their creation after the big bang they preserved their left-handedness (neutrinos in the [cosmic neutrino background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background), are supposed to be non-relativistic and to constitute the major part of the neutrinos, which is very hard to prove though).

Electrons, on the other hand, have electromagnetically interacted a lot with other electrically charged matter, so over time, they developed right- and lefthanded ones in equal amounts. In the same way, the non-relativistic neutrinos should also have developed right- and lefthanded ones in equal amounts, but this is, as I wrote, very hard to verify because of the very tiny masses of non-relativistic neutrinos. Only the (relativistic) neutrinos in standard experiments reveal that the neutrinos come exclusively in left-handed versions.

This implies of course, that the electrons had a velocity near the speed of light when they were created after the bang, just like the neutrinos. This is the case in different scenarios. I'm inclined to bring on the [Rishon Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishon_model) to discuss one of these scenarios but I can better refrain from doing so because it's pretty much non-mainstream, so I rather stick to the mainstream hypothesis that before the electroweak symmetry broke the electrons (and neutrinos) had no mass.

If the answer to this question is yes then the electron and electron-neutrino (and the muon and muon-neutrino, and the tau and tau-neutrino) are on a more equal footing or more symmetric with respect to each other (apart from the electric charge of the electron) than thought (and again I'm inclined to...).

I'm inclined to bring on the [Rishon Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishon_model), but I can better refrain from doing so because it's pretty much non-mainstream.

Comment: What "first electrons"? The electron is a massive Dirac spinor in QFT, helicity is not a Lorentz-invariant for it (neither is it for neutrinos if they're massive, but it's close), and it has both chiralities (as is necessary for a massive fermion).

Comment: @ACuriousMind  before symmetry breaking the elementary particles were massless, so yes there will be left handed electrons and right handed electrons  at that time, which is at about 10^-10 seconds after the big bang http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/unify.html#c1 . am I wrong?

Comment: @annav But why should neutrinos in that time all have the same chirality, while electrons dón't share all the same chirality?

Comment: @descheleschilder even with zero mass the electrons are charged and occupy a different representation than the massless neutrinos.

Comment: @annav So electric charge is the cause that massless electrons (which after the alleged symmetry break become massive and still move near the speed of light; the alleged Higgs field doesn't slow them down but only gives them mass, after which e.m. interactions can slow them down) can have two chiralities? I don't see why electric charge has an effect on spin and makes the massless electron spin in two directions.

Comment: @descheleschilder we have fitted an SU(2) electroweak group theory model to the data we have , a great number from accelerator experiments. This model has a symmetry breaking level in the available energy, due to the Higgs mechanism. This was introduced because of the observation of mass for these particles. When the energies are high and they are massless, before symmetry breaking, the particles still occupy the same group symmetry representations.  btw all fermions have different representations for 360 degrees phase change . It is how they couple to the W that differentiates them

Comment: and how they exchange quantum numbers, like charge. try this to realize the complexity http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/06/19/helicity-chirality-mass-and-the-higgs/

Comment: @annav Very interesting article, though in my view the Higgs mechanism exists only in the math. I realize now that if electrons were massless, like in the time before the alleged symmetry breaking, they would exist, just like the neutrinos (though neutrinos move nearly at the speed of light and thus have a very tiny mass), only in left-handed states. After they got heir mass, the number +1-and -1-helicity-electrons became the same. The question remains why only one type of handedness exists. I think it has to do with the structure of space, which may consist of (non-local) hidden variables.

Comment: @descheleschilder the handedness exists because of the parity violation of the weak interaction.